# How to order by a count(*) field?

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT xid, count(yid) AS tot
FROM x_y_map
WHERE z=11
GROUP BY xid
ORDER BY tot
```

The table is just a simple mapping of X's to Y's. Without the `ORDER BY` the query appears to work and displays the number of Y's each X has - one row for each X. However, adding the ordering, all I get is:

```
xid     yid
0       36503
```

Why is this happening, and how do I get the ordered list?

Comment: how many rows when there's no `where z = 11`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further research it looks like this is a bug in PHPMyAdmin. Running the same query through PHP gets the correct result. I think PMA is tripping up over so many rows for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

try direct count in order by like that:

```
ORDER BY count(yid)
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I just get the one row again, this time it's `273    36503`